# How to listen text while using Windows?

Tags: windows, pdf, text-to-speech, screen-reader

I want to listen instead of reading some e-books I downloaded (unprotected PDFs, that means that the text is machine readable without OCR).
I don't know how to make Windows Narrator to do this or if I need some other software.

Comment: while Windows Narrator Ctrl+Shift+Spacebar command works in Notepad, it doesn't work in my PDF Reader (Foxit)

Comment: I think that Windows Narrator works only with Notepad, Wordpad and few other products

Comment: I see this is from 2009. Foxit now supports text-to-speech. I'm using it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked [NaturalReader](http://www.naturalreaders.com/free_version.htm).

Comment: nice find, ty +1

Comment: Tried it, but didn't like it =( It integrates with any application that allows text selection, including Foxit, but the narration is less natural than Windows Narrator.

Answer (score 1):

**[CoolReader 2](http://coolreader.org/e-index.htm)** is my TTS (Read Aloud) software of choice, CR2 also converts text to mp3.

doesn't work with PDF though, you may use **[Calibre](http://calibre.kovidgoyal.net/)** to convert the PDF to TXT/RTF

*CoolReader 2 is free and portable.*

*Calibre is free.*